# Avoid ConcurrentModificationException on java stream using cache

Tags: java, caching, java-stream, spring-repositories, concurrentmodificationexception

I'm getting occasionally `ConcurrentModificationException` with the following code:

```
public Set<MyObject> getTypes(Set<Type> names) {
        Set<MyObject> myObjects = new HashSet<>();          
        myObjects = names.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(Type::getId)
                .mapToObj(cache::getMyObject)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I'm using cache to convert to `MyObject`, but exception seems to thrown in `collect` method (DAOImpl.java line 114)

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1558)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at com.dao.DAOImpl.getTypes(DAOImpl.java:114)
        at com.dao.DAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$affe23c4.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
        at com.dao.DAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6000bd7e.getTypes(<generated>)
```

How can I use cache to map to objects, or must I use cache outside stream?

Notice cache should be updated only 1 per day

Comment: If you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` it means that something is modifying `names` while streaming its entries. Is your `cache` somehow related to it? What else is modifying that collection?

Comment: Is your `cache` a plain `HashMap` by any chance?

Comment: @Kayaman cache is component which uses `Map`  implemented by `HashMap` to get the object by id

Comment: @DidierL `cache` isn't updating `names` and I don't see `names` modified

Comment: Is your cache thread-safe? I've never seen a proper cache implemented with a regular `HashMap`, there are obvious concurrency issues with it. `ConcurrentHashMap` can't throw a `CME` and it can be used as a simple cache as-is.

Comment: @Kayaman you may be correct, but the specific cache is daily basis, so it shouldn't be updated normally

Comment: Yet it's still being modified, as the exception shows. You've got a bug somewhere, whether a small bug in your caching, or a larger logic error in your daily caching.

Comment: I think this question really needs a [mre] because currently we can’t understand what’s going on.

Comment: (I am also a bit confused by the stacktrace because the calls between `HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining()` and `DAOImpl.getTypes()` make it look like if you were calling directly `names.stream().collect()` without any intermediate operation – but maybe I’m just missing something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that 2 threads changed `myObjects` so the expected count of the `Set` when looping through it was compromised, therefore the exception

The fix was to make the above service call atomic and therefore to prevent changing `Set` on runtime with a different thread

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related with your `cache::getMyObject`. The problem is that your `names` Set is being changed while you stream it, hence the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

If you wrap (create a new collection) from your `names` collection the problem is fixed.

```
public Set<MyObject> getTypes(Set<Type> names) {
        Set<MyObject> myObjects = new HashSet<>(names).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(Type::getId)
                .mapToObj(cache::getMyObject).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Nonetheless, I think your cache method (getMyObject) can return null. In that case you should filter them out.

If you want to trigger the exception you can do something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet();

    names.add("a");
    names.add("b");

    Thread x = new Thread(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        names.add("c");
      }
    };

    x.start();

    Set<Object> myObjects = new HashSet<>(names).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(s -> s.hashCode()).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i)).map(x1-> getx(x1)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

  }

  private static Object getx(String x) {

    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return x;
  }
```

Comment: Depending on what is the origin of the concurrent modification, `new HashSet<>(names)` could also throw a CME.

Comment: Why Set is being modified ? I don't modified it. do you know how can test your fix? because it isn't reproducible (happens every X hours)

Comment: Well, From the code you posted the most obvious explanation is names being changed. But there is a line in the exception that you posted  com.dao.DAOImpl.getTypes(DAOImpl.java:114 that now has called for my attention. If you say that you do not modify names, then what is cache:getMyObject and what is line 114 of DAOImpl?

Comment: @pringi line 114 is `.collect(Collectors.toSet());` in the code shown